Concatenating multiple ranges at runtime
What is the recommended way to concatenate (to chain) ranges the number of which is known at execution time only (of course, without copying the underlying data)?
I have many std::vector<float>s in different places and need to apply the same algorithm to them. Now I have to either call this algorithm to each vector or to write a wrapper which takes std::vector<std::vector<float>*>, fill this array and get to the first solution, passing through all pointers.
I figured out the following approach to handle this demo which works just fine so far (on godbolt my code is at the end of the listing):
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "concat.hpp"

struct S {
    std::vector <float> vec;
    int something_else=0;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> vectors;

    vectors.push_back({ { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f }, 0 });
    vectors.push_back({ { 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f }, 1 });
    
    std::vector<float> somewhere1 = { 7.0f, 8.0f, 9.0f };
    std::vector<float> somewhere2 = { 10.0f, 11.0f, 12.0f };

    auto jv = std::ranges::join_view(vectors | std::views::transform(&S::vec));
    auto cv = std::views::concat(jv, somewhere1);
    auto cv2 = std::views::concat(cv, somewhere2);

    for (auto& v : cv2) {
        std::cout << v << ", ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

The source code uses this concat.hpp.
The question is, since std::ranges::views::concat is not yet supported by all compilers, could the same result be achieved with std::ranges::join_view only without std::views::concat (I can’t find a way to add something that is not in the same std::vector). If so, how?
Overall, is the code above robust and correct in terms of usage of std::ranges::join_view and  std::views::concat for the considered task? If not, what approach could be recommended for this today?

Until you have support from the implementation, you could use rangesv3 as shown here

You could use a variadic function template like: https://godbolt.org/z/8adsf9b6o

@TedLyngmo, thank you for the input. Actually, I am totally fine with current draft of std::concat used in this example, I hope it is not worse than rangesv3's since it should be based on it. The overall question is if this solution is robust and this is the expected co-usage of these two algorithms, namely join_view for a dynamic amount of containers and concat for static amount of containers or I misuse? Additionally, am I correct that rangesv3 and std compatible with each other and I may use their types and algorithms in a mix not choosing one of them?

@NathanOliver, thank you, it helps. It seems that this is more generic and flexible solution (at least for my case). Am I correct that formally this would be as like I put all pointers to the vectors to std::array and pass it to the wrapper function? I mean, static allocation (on stack for most of architectures), compile-time aware of size, no dynamic allocation and etc. with the price of inability to have dynamic run-time size of the vectors to be passed to for_each_container?
